# How can I print SelectedRows in DBGrid using Rave Report?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, rave-reports

To report current record in dataset I have made (one record by page):

```
RvSystem1.SystemPrinter.FirstPage := DataSet.RecNo;
RvSystem1.SystemPrinter.LastPage := DataSet.RecNo;
```

So, how we can report only selected records in DataSet when all records appears in the same page. Something like:

```
RvProject1.SelectReport('Report1');
for I := 0 to DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count - 1 do begin
  /// ???
end;
  RvProject1.Execute;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that can be done by filtring DataSet with SelectedRows than execute report.